# using static methods between java files

Tags: java, android, static, non-static

I know there are other questions like this already asked but I still cannot get this fixed.

I have two activities in android studio, one is homePage.java and the other is newMessagePage.java. I am trying to use the getPermissiontoReadSMS method in the newMessagePage.java activity. Since it is in the homePage.java activity, I get the "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context error." Some suggestions in other posts included adding an instance of the method. I am still rather new to this and unsure how to go about it. Any help is appreciated.

homePage.java

```
public class homePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private boolean firstResume = false;

    ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView messages;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private static homePage inst;

    private static final int READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;



    public static homePage instance() {
        return inst;
    }

    public void getPermissionToReadSMS() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
            if(grantResults.length == 1 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read SMS permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                refreshSmsInbox();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read SMS permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");

        if(indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            String str = "SMS from: " + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                    "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
            arrayAdapter.add(str);
        } while(smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());

        }


    private void addDrawerItems() {
    //side drawer things
        String[] osArray = { "Sent", "Patients", "Folders", "Trash", "Settings" };
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(position == 4) {

                    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(homePage.this, settingsPage.class);
                    startActivity(settingsIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void FABListener() {
    //FAB button functions
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent newMessage = new Intent(homePage.this, newMessagePage.class);
                startActivity(newMessage);
            }
        });
    }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        messages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
        messages.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getPermissionToReadSMS();
        }else {
            refreshSmsInbox();
        }

        addDrawerItems();
        FABListener();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(firstResume) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
        firstResume = false;
    }
}
```

newMessagePage.java

```
public class newMessagePage extends AppCompatActivity {

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
EditText input;

public void onSendClick(View view) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //insert reference to getPermissionToReadSMS method here


    }else {

        smsManager.sendTextMessage("07747689961", null, input.getText().toString(), null, null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_message_page);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
}
```

}

Comment: which line is the error on?

Comment: in the newMessagePage.java file. I put a comment where the correction should be.

Comment: you could make getpermissiontoreadsms a static function, but code-apprentice says that's bad. I'm not an andriod expert so i'd listen to him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this! Static methods and variables are the exception not the rule. In Android, they can cause particularly nasty bugs, especially with what you are doing here. Trying to access the methods of an activity which is not currently active and displayed on the screen will cause serious problems with your app. Most likely it will crash. Instead of static methods, you need to learn about the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) and work with it so that you do not accidentally leak memory and other resources.

In order to share the functionality of a method between activities, you have at least three options:

1. Create a class with the method then declare a variable of that class inside each activity.
2. Create an abstract class which extends AppCompatActivity. Add the method to this class then extend this class for each of your activities rather than extending AppCompatActivity.
3. Create a "utility class" with the method and make it static.

The first option is often the most preferred because it provides the most flexibility. You can declare as many variables as you like to provide different functionality.

The second option is okay, but it locks you into an inheritance hierarchy that can be very limiting since you can only extend one class.

The third option is only for a last resort because `static` methods do not follow Object Oriented principles.

Comment: Yes, other posts similar to this one have mentioned that but I am not too sure what it means or how it would pertain to static vs. non-static methods. I am still new to android studio and java.

Comment: Here's a hint, that method doesn't need to be attached to your activity, you can generalize it and put it in a helper class or just duplicate it in your other Activity. However, the Overridden method onRequestPermissionsResult needs to be in every activity where you request permissions.

Comment: @HernanRazo I have added some suggestions for sharing a method between Activity classses.

Comment: While @DaveS is right that onRequestPermissionsResult needs to be in each activity (either directly or inherited) it may delegate to some other shared method to reduce code duplication.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice could you perhaps give an example to how each option's code would look like? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HernanRazo I have provided enough information abs keywords that you can google for some Java tutorials to learn from. Inheritance and composition are two essential concepts to master.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice alright thanks, you've helped me out a lot!

Comment: @HernanRazo Thank you for your polite and professional reaction. Good luck with learning Java and Android. Come back with any other specific question you have as you are learning.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
public static void getPermissionToReadSMS(AppCompatActivity context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (context.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            context.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```